# File transfer over Socket in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, stream, filestream

I have managed to write code to transfer file over Socket in C# between two PCs.

I have been scratching my head for a couple of days, trying to figure out where the problem lies.

The seems to work only when I debug and stepover everything.

Following is the relevant mashed together version of my code.

Server side:

```
    internal async Task TransferProc() 
     { 
         
         while (Index < fileSize) 
         { 
             
  
          
             try 
             {
                 FS!.Position = Index; 
  
                 var read = await FS.ReadAsync(file_buffer, 0, file_buffer.Length); 
                 await FS.FlushAsync(); 
                 using var ms = new MemoryStream(); 
                 using var pw = new BinaryWriter(ms); 
  
                 { 


               If(!isFileNameSent)
                 {
            FS = new FileStream(somefile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
               pw.Write(filename);
               pw.Write(fileSize); 
               isFileNameSent= true;

                 }
                     
                     pw.Write(file_buffer); 
  
                 
                     Transferred += read; 
                     Index += read; 
  
                    
                    await SendData(ms.ToArray())
                 } 
             } 
             catch (Exception) 
             { 
                 throw; 
             } 
           
         } 
         //Cleanup Code
     }


     var SocketWriteStream = _baseSocket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite(); 
     var SocketReadStream = _baseSocket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();

public Task SendData(byte[] data) 
     { 
         
         lock (lockObj) // necessary as method is called by multiple objects to transfer data.
         { 
             try 
             { 
                 
                 //Send the size of the data. 
  
                 SocketWriteStream!.WriteAsync(BitConverter.GetBytes(data!.Length), 0, 4); 
  
                 //And then the actual data. 
  
                 SocketWriteStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length); 
                 SocketWriteStream.FlushAsync(); 
             } 
             catch (Exception) 
             { 
                 
                 throw; 
             } 
         } 
     }
```

And Now on the client side:

```
public async Task<bool> StartClient() 
     { 
         while (true) 
         { 
             try 
             { 
                 var bytesRead = await SocketReadStream!.ReadAsync(_buffer!, 0, 4); 
  
                 if (bytesRead > 0) 
                 { 
                     var size = BitConverter.ToInt32(_buffer!, 0); 
                     
                     if (size > _buffer.Length) 
                     { 
                         _buffer = new byte[size]; 
                         Debug.WriteLine($"Buffer size {_buffer.Length} and size {size}"); 
                     } 
                     var read = await SocketReadStream.ReadAsync(_buffer!, 0, size); //EXCEPTION A
                     await SocketReadStream.FlushAsync(); 
                    

        using var pr = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(_buffer )); 


        If(!isFileNameRecd)
           { 
   var fileName = pr.ReadString(); 
        
      var length = pr.ReadInt64();

      var path= Path.Combine(someFolder, fileName)

      FS = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate); //EXCEPTION B
isFileNameRecd= true;

}
                     
                    

                    var bytes = pr.ReadBytes(size);

        await FS.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
         await FS.FlushAsync();

  
               
                 } 
                 else 
                 { 
                    
                     Debug.WriteLine("Run Closed"); 
  
                
                 } 
             } 
             catch (Exception e) 
             { 
                 Debug.WriteLine($"Socket was closed! due to {e.Message} and {e.InnerException?.Message}"); 
                 
                 throw; 
             } 
         } 
     }
```

Now I face two exceptions as below,

EXCEPTION A: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

EXCEPTION B: Could not find a part of the path *PartialPathToFile*.

What I have tried:

If I debug with breakpoint at Exception A and keep stepping over I dont face any issue and data is recd with complete integrity.

Problem:

Exception A and B randomly occur, if the code is run without any breakpoint.

Somehow the size of packet recd increases way more than buffer.Length from server, which bothers me the most in the client side ReadAsync method.

Things to note:

Data is read from SSD and the read operation is completed in an instant.

I have adjusted buffer on both sides keeping in view of other file metadata.

I have typed this whole question on mobile, so please pardon the formatting and all.

I'm still learning programming as whole.

Comment: If you get errors that your array is to small, check where the error occur, and how large your array is. The debugger should be able to tell you this. You may use the callstack window to jumpto the correct piece of code. Next step is to figure out *why* the array is to small, and that is an exercise in following the program flow and figure out what is happening.

Comment: @JonasH I have been doing just that since yesterday, array on both server and client side are of same length. Even then I had put this block of code on the client side `if (size > _buffer.Length) 
                     { 
                         _buffer = new byte[size]; 
                         Debug.WriteLine($"Buffer size {_buffer.Length} and size {size}"); 
                     } `. Still the error is thrown. That is what I'm not able to figure out, why the exception A or B is thrown. Exception is not thrown when I debug and stepover.

Comment: Behavioral changes when debugging are often an indication of race conditions or other threading issues. Multi threading is difficult. Using async code may be fine, but you should be very careful to ensure there is only a single thread running at a time if you want to avoid multi threading issues. I would just use synchronous calls to be safe. Ofc, I would use a higher level protocol, like MQTT or gRPC instead of sockets.

Comment: The best way of debugging these intermit tents is to write error message to console or to a file without stopping to you can debug issues without adding break points.  The filename issue is due to not using ReadLine() which waits until the CR is found and the end of the filename string.  The socket in windows uses timers and a send message may not get read in one chunk on receiver and that is why you are only getting a partial filename.

Comment: `I'm still learning programming as whole.` I don't mean to sound harsh, but you're tackling two complex topics (asynchronous programming and TCP/IP communication) while learning programming. If you're learning, then start with the basics. Async is more intermediate, and TCP/IP is very advanced.
That said, if you really want to learn async TCP/IP, I have a [video series on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIebvSMVr_dehKSoq6vuAW0BGEM6QnDlS).